# Vainglory with iPad Pro Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, vainglory

Is it possible to play Vainglory on the iPad Pro in conjunction with a keyboard connected to the iPad via Smart Connector? I have seen [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCyWEWXIcgQ) by Austin Evans where he attempts to do this with a different game, but I'm wondering if it is at all possible to do this with any keyboard, or if games still need MFi (Made For iOS) controllers in order to support such interaction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Keyboards will not work for spells on vainglory. You have to actually tap or click them. however if you use a mouse, you can use the mouse to click on the spells (highly inefficient however).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no
Long answer: Vainglory is designed to be played by using touch input's only. Of course if you ran it in an Android simulator you could map key commands to certain places of the screen. In theory.